# Jquery console.log gives two different objects

Tags: jquery, object, console.log

I'm a newbie at Jquery, so I give myself some small things to work on. For now, I'm trying to make a basic 'Read less' and 'Read More' button. I got a lot of it working, but there's one thing that keep bugging me. Here's a bit of my code:

```
$(".ReadMore").click(function() {
    var numbers = ($(this).attr('id'));
    $(".cat." + numbers).css("max-height", "9000px");
    $(this).css("opacity", "0");

    console.log($(".ReadLess#" + numbers).css("opacity", "1"));
});
```

And the read less:

```
$(".ReadLess").click(function() {
    var numbers = ($(this).attr('id'));

    $(".cat." + numbers).css("max-height", "230px");
    console.log($(".ReadMore#" + numbers).css("opacity", "1"));
});
```

As yo ucan see, they're almost the same. The readmore function works perfectly for me. However, the read less doesn't. It make the .cat the good height, but the Readmore doesn't appear like it should. I tried to console log it, and I see a bit of a deffierence, whta does it mean, and how do i get it to work.

[image]

EDIT:

Here the html of the two buttons:

```
"<div class='ReadMore' id='$column_count' style='display: block; ' > ";
                echo "Read more ...";
                echo "</div>";    


"<div class='ReadLess' id='$column_count'  style='display: block '>";

                                echo "Read less...";

                                echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code readably when asking for help.

Comment: Your `id` values start with digits. That's fine, but you cannot use them with CSS ID selectors unless you escape them. That is, `.ReadLess#6` is an invalid CSS selector which will not work reliably cross-browser. I would strongly suggest using `id`s that *don't* start with digits, as it's the simpler course of action.

Comment: *"I see a bit of a deffierence, whta does it mean"* ***What*** difference? Sure, we might be able to find something different, but we'd have no guarantee that it's the same thing you're taking about.

Comment: We need to see the HTML as well.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, first of all. When I try to _console.log_ the last lines of the functions (as you can see in my code), they both give a different answers back. The first one starts with "div#6.ReadLess, prev..." while the other starts with "prevObject: m.fn....". That's the difference i wanted to talk about. Why does it show two different answers while they're (in my eyes) the same code.

Comment: Yup, the problem is using the same `id` on more than one element. But there are lots of other things you can do to simplify this as well, I've covered it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What that's telling you is that no element matching the selector `.ReadMore#6` was found. That's why the `length` of the jQuery object is `0` and why there's no `0` property (jQuery objects are a bit like arrays), whereas in the first example with the `.ReadLess#6` selector, `length` is `1` and there's a `0` property which refers to the one element that matched.

Looking at the HTML you posted (well, close enough, the server-side code that generates it), you have more than one element with `id="6"` (and such). That's invalid, there can only be a **single** element with `id="6"` in a document.

So the fix is not use the same `id` on more than one element.

You probably don't need `id` values at all, depending on the structure if your document. In your event handlers, `this` refers to the specific element that was clicked, and so you can use it to navigate to the thing whose size you want to change.

So I suspect you could do this:

```
$(".ReadMore").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cat = $this.closest(".cat");
    cat.css("max-height", "9000px");
    $this.css("opacity", 0);                  // Side note: Don't use strings
    cat.find(".ReadLess").css("opacity", 1);  // ...for opacity
});

$(".ReadLess").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cat = $this.closest(".cat");
    cat.css("max-height", "230px");
    $this.css("opacity", 0);
    cat.find(".ReadMore").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

But it can be a lot simpler if you control visibility and height with classes rather than direct manipulation. Here's a simple example:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ReadMore", function() {
  // Use `this` to figure out what entry we're in
  var entry = $(this).closest(".Entry");
  
  // Show more
  entry.addClass("ShowMore");
});
$(document).on("click", ".ReadLess", function() {
  // Use `this` to figure out what entry we're in
  var entry = $(this).closest(".Entry");
  
  // Don't show more
  entry.removeClass("ShowMore");
});
// Note that unless you really need separate handlers,
// you could just use a single one:
// $(document).on("click", ".ReadMore, .ReadLess", function() {
  // $(this).closest(".Entry").toggleClass("ShowMore");
// });
```

```css
/* Normally, "more" isn't showing */
.Entry .More {
  display: none;
}
/* But when we add ShowMore to the entry, it is */
.Entry.ShowMore .More {
  display: block;
}
/* Also make the div taller and give it a border when showing more, just as an example */
.Entry.ShowMore {
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
/* Float our "buttons" */
.ReadMore, .ReadLess {
  float: right;
}
/* Normally, "ReadLess" isn't showing */
.Entry .ReadLess {
  display: none;
}
/* But it is when we're showing more */
.Entry.ShowMore .ReadLess {
  display: inline;
}
/* When we're showing more, don't show "ReadMore" */
.Entry.ShowMore .ReadMore {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Entry">
  <span class="ReadMore">more</span>
  <span class="ReadLess">less</span>
  First entry - this is the text always shown
  <div class="More">
    First entry - this is only shown when there's more
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Entry">
  <span class="ReadMore">more</span>
  <span class="ReadLess">less</span>
  Second entry - this is the text always shown
  <div class="More">
    Second entry - this is only shown when there's more
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Entry">
  <span class="ReadMore">more</span>
  <span class="ReadLess">less</span>
  Third entry - this is the text always shown
  <div class="More">
    Third entry - this is only shown when there's more
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've used classes to control what's going on rather than direct `css` calls, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: This might be actually it. I use the ID on both the ReadLess AND ReadMore, dumb fault on my part. I'm going to try to use your code, thank you!